# Comparing two dates in android studio

Tags: date, android-studio, time

I want to get the current date and time and compare  it to a set date and time.   All I can do right now is display the date and time on the screen.  Can you help please?

Comment: Did you check the date api in java?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating the difference between two Java date instances](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555262/calculating-the-difference-between-two-java-date-instances)